# Does CUBRID have Information Schema Views?

Tags: information-schema, code

**I am trying to access the Information Schema views as defined in SQL92, and cannot find any in the CUBRID RDBMS. Has CUBRID implemented this specification and how can I access them?**

CUBRID version: CUBRID 10.1, manual: https://www.cubrid.org/manual/en/10.1/

**There is something called System Catalog: https://www.cubrid.org/manual/en/10.1/sql/catalog.html, is this possibly the same, and why is it not called "information_schema" as specified in the SQL92 specification?**

When querying the database for my table `book` i get following:

```
SELECT * FROM db_class WHERE class_name LIKE 'book'; 

class_name = book
owner_name = DBA
class_type = CLASS
is_system_class = NO
partitioned = NO
is_reuse_oid_class = YES
collation = iso88591_bin
comment =
```

**Are there no schemas in CUBRID?**

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                                .withDriver(DRIVER)
                                .withUrl(URI))
                .withGenerator(new Generator()
                                .withGenerate(new Generate()
                                                .withDaos(true)
                                                .withImmutablePojos(true))
                                .withDatabase(new Database()
                                                .withName(DATABASE)
                                                // .withIncludes(".*")
                                                // .withExcludes("")
                                                .withInputSchema("jq"))
                                .withTarget(new Target()
                                                .withPackageName(PACKAGE)
                                                .withDirectory(DIRECTORY)
                                                .withClean(true)))
                .withLogging(Logging.TRACE);

        GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
```

**I need it for code-generation with JOOQ, what catalog/schema do I have to specify?**

Comment: anyone with enough points: please introduce the tag '**jooq**', thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it. It works only if you fully remove any schema or catalog information:**

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                                .withDriver(DRIVER)
                                .withUser(USER)
                                .withPassword(PASSWORD)
                                .withUrl(URI))
                .withGenerator(new Generator()
                                .withGenerate(new Generate()
                                                .withDaos(true)
                                                .withPojos(true)
                                                .withImmutablePojos(true))
                                .withDatabase(new Database()
                                                .withName(DATABASE)
                                                .withIncludes(".*")
                                                .withExcludes("_?db_.*?"))
                                .withTarget(new Target()
                                                .withPackageName(PACKAGE)
                                                .withDirectory(DIRECTORY)
                                                .withClean(true)))
                .withLogging(Logging.TRACE);

        GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
```

This archived manual page of the CUBRID project was also helpful: https://web.archive.org/web/20160819080919/https://www.cubrid.org/wiki_apps/entry/jooq-cubrid-tutorial